# How can the new WebView2 WinForms control be added to the Toolbox in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, winui, winui-3

I'm trying to mess around with the new control but for some reason I can't seem to get it into the Toolbox. I tried manually injecting it into the designer code but then modifying the form overwrote my changes. I'm on the latest VS preview + latest pre-release of WebView2, also have the latest Edge Beta installed on Windows 10.

Comment: its listed as a wip: https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html